# Pass parameter into UserControl from Master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

Bear with me, first time with UserControls and this is a big application I'm inheriting...

I have a user control in a master page. That works. I need to reuse about 99% of it barring one conditional css class. My thought was to key off the ID and return the correct class.

.ascx:

```
<div class="<%= GetMyClass() %>">Changes colors!</div>
```

.ascx.cx:

```
public string GetMyClass(){
    if (ID == "FirstId"){
        return "first-class";
    } 
    if (ID == "SecondId"){
        return "second-class";
    }
    return "";
}
```

.master:

```
<slc:MyUsercontrol runat="server" ID="FirstId" />
... stuff
<slc:MyUsercontrol runat="server" ID="SecondId" />
```

Two things happened here.

First, with a breakpoint in my codebehind for the user control, it only breaks once, where I would expect it to break twice.

Second, the `ID` available in the codebehind is not the "ID" passed in to the page. If I change "FirstId" to "Slamalamadingdong" the value is still "FirstId" in the codebehind when it hits my breakpoint.

Note that "FirstId" was set when I inherited the project, I added the markup with "SecondId", so I'm supposing that this value is actually set up somewhere else completely and the markup value is irrelevant when we get to the codebehind.

Am I completely off base in how I'm trying to pull this off?

Comment: Did you recompile the project or just reload the page in a browser after making your changes?

Comment: @Maxx Recompiled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass a parameter into the UserControl, instead of relying on the `ID` expose a new property for the UserControl as so:

.ascx.cx:

```
public string MyClass { get; set; }
```

.ascx:

```
<div class="<%= MyClass %>">Changes colors!</div>
```

.master:

```
<slc:MyUsercontrol runat="server" ID="FirstId" MyClass="first-class" />

<slc:MyUsercontrol runat="server" ID="SecondId" MyClass="second-class" />
```

This is a much more generic approach since you can simply add other `MyUsercontrol` elements with their own behavior without changing `MyUsercontrol`'s logic. Also coupling the UserControl logic with the `ID` from his parent is not a good idea.